# How to change margin and padding of textview - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, margin, padding

How to change margin and padding of textview in kotlin? I've tried this:

```
  val maskot_names = maskot_row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maskot_name)
            maskot_names.text=maskot_names_list.get(position)

            // showing "???" if maskot_names is empty
            if(maskot_names.text=="")
            {
                maskot_names.text="？？？"
                maskot_names.paddingTop(16f) 
            }
```

Comment: `I've tried this:` and what was the result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to call `setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

like so:

`maskot_names.setPadding(0,16,0,0)`

What you are trying to use is only the getter.

Android studio shows what `padding...()` actually means in java:

[image: padding example]

The image shows it only calls `getPadding...()`

If you want to add a margin to your `TextView` you will have to `LayoutParams`:

```
val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
params.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
maskot_names.layoutParams = params
```

Comment: Thanx for your help :)

Comment: @TazwarUtshas No Problem!